# Issue tracking - how to add gridlines in SP 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, issue-tracking

I'm using Issue Tracking in SP 2013 for a fairly simple table of 5 columns and 8 rows.  All I need to do is add gridlines to the table, so it looks nicer and is easier to read.
Adding gridlines was easy in SP 2010 using the SP Designer, but I can't figure out how to add the lines in SP 2013.  The WYSIWYG option is MIA!

Can you help?

Answer (score 0):

You can apply some CSS to color odd rows of tables with class `ms-listviewtable`,
add it to your MasterPage, edit the page in Designer, or add a Content Editor WepPart.

```
<STYLE>
.ms-listviewtable tbody tr:nth-child(odd){
    background-color:rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.5);
}
</STYLE>
```